# Adding more graphs to the Linode dashboard

Tags: linux, monitoring, linode

Linode offers system monitoring graphs as shown below.

[image]

Is it possible to add more graphs to the Linode dashboard by way of **collectd**? Say to view Memcache eviction rate.

Just to give you an idea this is the interface of RightScale, a deployment and management solution I use on Ec2.

[image]
Whenever a RightScale template is booted it comes with a default set of collectd configuration. If I need more I just have to add the collect config or template for that.

Say I write a collectd plugin to monitor memcached evictions.  Collectd is configured to send this to a RightScale monitoring server and it relays back to the interface.
Linode obviously is monitoring in some similar fashion since the basic system health is seen in the dashboard.

Comment: Munin is a pretty good solution http://munin-monitoring.org/

Answer (score 2):

Linode has no access into whats going on in your Linode, so no, it is not possible. You will need run run your own monitoring solution.

Comment: hmm. collectd could send it to any configured machine run by linode. This is the way RightScale does .

Comment: Well you can lobby the Linode staff to add that functionality, but I highly doubt it's going to happen. You asked if it was possible *now*, and it is not.